# Why and how firefox shows youtube video despite all plugins are disabled, including Shockwave flash ones?

Tags: firefox, flash, plugins

When I open a video url I see a div with the message:

```
This plugin is disabled.
   manage plugins...
```

Then in few seconds the video starts. Why? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is using the html5 technology to show the video. This is a quite new technique. You can find more information at http://youtube.com/html5